# Finding Correct java files with the help if System property in ANT

Tags: ant, junit

I have a System property named : ITEM_ROOTDIR.tests. It has a value of abc,xyz. With ANT based task, how do I find abc.java and xyz.java in the src folder ? (src folder is in basedir, and basedir has been declared to ".") Once I find the files, can I use these multiple files in the include task ? If not how to include them ?

It will be preferred to just find the files and store the result back in ITEM_ROOTDIR.tests.and then use the property again in include task.

Comment: The include task in ANT is used pull in other build files, not java. Unclear what you're trying to achieve with this request.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor: You are right. I will use other attributes such as includes or includesfile. What I am trying to achieve is to "Allow user to run multiple Junit test classes in the same build." Jenkins parameters are usually retrieved as System property in build.xml. Now, if that system property has multiple values like abc,xyz,asd etc. How do I find files with identical names ?(e.g. abc.java,xyz.java,asd.java) and once I find them how can I make ANT run tests in those files ? Does that make it clearer ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you're creating work for yourself by running tests individually.

This is my standard test target:

```
<target name="test" depends="compile" description="Run unit tests">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/tests"/>

    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="${junit.haltonfailure}">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="runtime.path"/>
            <pathelement path="${classes.dir}"/>
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="plain"/>
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${build.dir}/tests">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*Test*.java"/>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Runs the tests in my "src" directory, generating a consolidated report for all tests.

## Update

Tests taking too long to run is a very common problem. The standard answer is to refactor your tests to make them go faster..... :-(

Opinions vary, but in my experience the best solution is divide your tests into different categories.

- Unit tests (mocked, so should run fast and covers all features)
- fast integration tests
- slow integration tests.

I run unit tests as part of my build and the integration tests as separate Jenkins jobs (post-deployment). This addresses my need for immediate feedback and divides my test reporting into 3 categories, rather than forcing me to track each individual test.

Another argument against individual testing is that in a large team you don't see the effect your changes have on other parts of the codebase. It's a team effort after all :-)

Comment: Mark, I have the same. But what if all tests take 30 minutes and user can't wait that long ? In such cases, user may just want to run test scripts related to some important module and be done with it in 10 minutes. Also, I know running them parallel is an option but we are not there yet and besides parallel tests do not give well organized console output when all tests run at the same time.